# Python: How do I take an imported text file with a list of names, two column format, and put them in python sorted alphabetically?

Tags: python

This is what I have so far and its giving me errors when sort(), sorted() are used.
I have to import the names and print them.
Sort the names and print them again.

The text file is formatted in two columns and is from notepad

```
Riggs, Jerry
Stone, Ruby
Wood, Holly
Dover, Ilene
Funt, Ella
Storm, Wayne
Lowe, Lyle
Free, Bjorn
Caine, Candy
Carr, Rex
Downs, Mark
Twain, Lionel
Thorn, Rose
Shore, Rocky
Bush, Rose
Waters, Muddy
Graves, Doug
Stone, Roxanne
Rivers, Wade
Banks, Rob
Carr, Rusty
Trout, Brooke
Carr, Rhoda
Apple, Adam
Ponds, Lily
Burns, Forest
Dover, Ben
Sales, Clarence
Nichol, Penny
Beech, Sandy
```

I just can't get it to alphabetically sort the names or how to go about doing it. The desired outcome is that it will print the same style as the text file, in two columns.

```
def main():
    infile = open('names.txt','r')
    str = infile.read()
    print(str)
    name = str

    for name in str:
        ch = 'X'
        print(name)

    #for line in str:
        #str = line.readlines()
        #print(line)

    name = input('Who are you looking for? (case sensitive):') 
    if name in str:
        print(name,'was found in the list')
    else:
        print(name,'was not found in the list')
    infile.close()

main()
```

Comment: This is the code. Im not sure what to edit? I just cant get the code to sort() being everything imported is a str and I can't use sort().

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear about how this file should be parsed and alphabetized. Are we alphabetizing on the first name or the second name? I'm not clear on the point of `ch = 'X'`. `str = ` overwrites a builtin function--pick a different variable name.

Comment: It has to be sorted by last name. The ch = 'X' was my attempt to get it to stop showing an error.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I recommend making another edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, Hope this will help:

```
def main():
  with open('data.txt') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

  list_str = sorted(data.split("\n"))
  print("\n".join(list_str))

  name = input('Who are you looking for? (case sensitive:') 
  if name in list_str:
      print(name,'was found in the list')
  else:
      print(name,'was not found in the list')

main()
```

Ouput:

```
Apple, Adam
Banks, Rob
Beech, Sandy
Burns, Forest
Bush, Rose
Caine, Candy
Carr, Rex
Carr, Rhoda
Carr, RustyDover, Ben
Dover, Ilene
Downs, Mark
Free, Bjorn
Funt, Ella
Graves, Doug
Lowe, Lyle
Nichol, Penny
Ponds, Lily
Riggs, Jerry
Rivers, Wade
Sales, Clarence
Shore, Rocky
Stone, Roxanne
Stone, Ruby
Storm, Wayne
Thorn, Rose
Trout, Brooke
Twain, Lionel
Waters, Muddy
Wood, Holly

Who are you looking for? (case sensitive: Apple, Adam
Apple, Adam was found in the list
```

Comment: I was able to get this, however it needs to be in the same format as the text file in the program. I shouldv'e mentioned that in the explanation.

Comment: @koolrob88, i hope now it is in correct format. Please upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have got the contents of the file in a string. Instead, you need a list, and for that, you could either of these:

```py
infile = open('names.txt','r')
names = infile.read().split('\n')
```

or better yet,

```py
names = infile.readlines()
```

After that, sorting is straightforward:

```py
sorted_names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split(', ')[1]) #if you want to sort on first names
sorted_names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split(', ')[0]) #if you want to sort on last names
```